# How to make hover effect for two bar in highcharts at the same time is there any way by using css or any inbuilt method to achieve this?

Tags: css, highcharts

I'm trying to create a hover effect for two bar at the same time, is there any possibility to achieve this by using any existing method or external css to achieve this kind of hover effect, on hover event present in highcharts I can only change the colour of the single bar image.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highstock/6.0.3/highstock.src.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/xrange.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100px"></div>
```

**Highcharts**

```
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        time: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });

    Highcharts.chart('container',{
        chart:{
            type : 'xrange',
            backgroundColor : '0C0D19',
            renderTo:'container',
            marginRight: 100,
        },
       colors : ['#45AD59','#6699FF'],
        title : { text : '' },
        credits : { enabled : false },
        legend : { enabled : false },
        exporting : {
            buttons : {
                contextButton : {
                    enabled : false
                }
            }
        },
        plotOptions : {
            series : {
                cursor : 'pointer',
            }
        },
        tooltip : {  enabled: false },
        xAxis : {
            type : 'datetime',
            opposite : true,
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            showLastLabel: true,
            tickLength: 0,
            tickInterval:3600*1000,
            gridLineColor:'#2c2d39',
            gridLineWidth:1,
            min : 1545281770000,
            minPadding: 0,
            dateTimeLabelFormats : {
                millisecond: '%I:%M %P',
                second: '%I:%M %P',
                minute: '%I:%M %P',
                hour: '%I:%M %P',
                day: '%I:%M %P',
                week: '%I:%M %P',
                month: '%I:%M %P',
                year: '%I:%M %P'
            },
            crosshair : {
                snap : false,
                zIndex : 100,
                label: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{value:%I:%M %P}'
                }
            },
            labels : {
                align : 'left',
                style : {
                    color : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)',
                    fontSize : '12px'
                }
            },
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
             plotBands: [{
                from: -0.21001,
                to: 0.3291,
                color: '#00401f'
            },{
                from:0.5570,
                to:1.275,
                color:'#2f4776'
             }],

            categories: ['Reported','Tracked'],
            reversed: true,
            labels:{
                align:'center',
                style:{
                    color:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)',
                    fontSize:'12px'
                },
                formatter: function() {
                    return  this.value + '<img></img>';
                },
                useHTML: true
            },
            lineColor: '#2c2d39',
            lineWidth: 1
        },
        series: [{
            pointWidth: 20,
            borderWidth:0,
            borderRadius:0,
            data : [{
                "x": 1545281770000,
                "x2": 1545284950000,
                "y": 1,
                "floor": 3,
                "room": "3001",
                "value": true,
                "hoverId": 0
                }, {
                    "x": 1545285388000,
                    "x2": 1545291448000,
                    "y": 1,
                    "floor": 3,
                    "room": "3001",
                    "value": true,
                    "hoverId": 1,
                }, {
                    "x": 1545303407000,
                    "x2": 1545312167000,
                    "y": 1,
                    "floor": 2,
                    "room": "2001",
                    "value": true,
                    "hoverId": 2,
                }, {
                    "x": 1545312218000,
                    "x2": 1545312338000,
                    "y": 1,
                    "floor": 3,
                    "room": "3000",
                    "value": true,
                    "hoverId": 3,
                }, {
                    "x": 1545314138000,
                    "x2": 1545314738000,
                    "y": 1,
                    "floor": 2,
                    "room": "2001",
                    "value": true,
                    "hoverId": 4,
                }
                    ,{
                    x:1545281701745,
                    x2:1545285267354,
                    y:0,
                },  
                {
                    x:1545285327157,
                    x2:1545292261051,
                    y:0,
                },{
                    x:1545303345999,
                    x2:1545314757609,
                    y:0,
                    className:'manual',
                }
                    ],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }]
    })
```

**CSS**

```
 #container .highcharts-grid.highcharts-yaxis-grid path{
    display: none;
 }
 #container .highcharts-axis.highcharts-xaxis path{
    display: none;
 }
 #container .highcharts-point.highcharts-point.highcharts-color-0 rect{
    height: 15px;
    y: 8;
 }
 #container .highcharts-point.highcharts-point.highcharts-color-1 rect{
    y: 27;
    height: 18px;
 }
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karnan796/8rke2L9d/11/show)

Comment: jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/karnan796/8rke2L9d/11/show

Comment: Are you sure that what you've got is CSS? I don't recall any properties named just `y`, and you would have to specify a unit like `px` along it's value.

Comment: @james-douglas css which i have posted are related to highcharts, y point for the axis, if there is any way to use js mouseover to show a dynamic div like that?

Comment: @JamesDouglas, [`y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/y) is a perfectly legal attribute on [`<rect>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect), which is what points are rendered as on the displayed chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it using `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` which allows you to plot a rectangle and `Highcharts.SVGElement.on` method which allows you to add events on SVG elements (for example series group). Check demo and code posted below.

Code:

```
  chart: {
    type: 'xrange',
    backgroundColor: '0C0D19',
    renderTo: 'container',
    marginRight: 100,
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var chart = this,
          series = chart.series[0],
          seriesSvg = series.group,
          seriesSvgBBox = seriesSvg.getBBox(),
          width = 80,
          height = seriesSvgBBox.height,
          y = chart.plotTop + seriesSvgBBox.y,
          x,
          tooltip;

        seriesSvg.on('mousemove', function(e) {
          if (tooltip) {
            tooltip.destroy();
          }

          x = e.offsetX - width / 2

          tooltip = chart.renderer
            .rect(x, y, width, height)
            .attr({
              fill: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
            })
            .css({
              'pointer-events': 'none'
            })
            .add()
            .toFront();
        });

        seriesSvg.on('mouseout', function(e) {
          tooltip.destroy();
          tooltip = null;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z2h59pLf/2/

**API reference:** 
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect 
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#on

Comment: thanks @Wojciech , is there any way to set the width dynamic, with respect to the blue bar width?

Comment: Yes of course. You have access to each point width through `series.points` array. So, each time rectangle is rendered you can set its width dynamically depend on particular point width. Check the console in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z2h59pLf/2/